# nullpointer because of toggle button?

Tags: android

I use this code to set the view

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
```

and i then i have this code to get infromation up on screen

```
 Cursor MainPageCursor = databaseHelper.fetchAllReminders();
     startManagingCursor(MainPageCursor);


     String[] empty = new String[] { DatabaseStore.MUTE_TITLE,  DatabaseStore.START_KEY_TIME, DatabaseStore.END_KEY_TIME, DatabaseStore.COVERT_DAYS }; 



        int[] notempty = new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2, R.id.text4,  R.id.text5};
        SimpleCursorAdapter mainPageList = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.editinfo_row,MainPageCursor, empty, notempty);
       setListAdapter(mainPageList);
```

but the problem i have is i need to get a toggle button into each item row in the simplecursoradapter but if i put it into the simplecursoradapter layout R.layout.editinfo_row i get a nullpointer exception how do i fix that?

update - editinfo_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/widget38"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" - "
                android:textSize="30sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp" />


        <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textOn="main"
        android:textOff="off"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</LinearLayout>



  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

logcat:

```
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.seanoneill.android.SilentPhone/com.seanoneill.android.SilentPhone.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at com.seanoneill.android.SilentPhone.MainActivity.addListenerOnButton(MainActivity.java:190)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at com.seanoneill.android.SilentPhone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-30 16:31:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21484):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You should show the code (xml or java) that you use to put your button in the layout as well as the logcat showing the error.  What you have given does not tell us what you did wrong when you tried to add the button.

Comment: Ok, the issue isn't adding the button, it's something in your listener... `at com.seanoneill.android.SilentPhone.MainActivity.addListenerOnButton(MainActivity.java:190)`.  What is that line (probably be most helpful to post the whole method containing that line).  At a guess you are trying to set a listener outside of your adapter... which won't work when the button will have multiple instances.  You need to set the listener inside a custom SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: this is at line 190:  toggleButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ...... is custom adapter much differnt to simplecursoradapter to implement toogle button?

Comment: It is pretty much the same, you just do it in the `getView` method of the adapter.  That way there is an instance for each row, and you can use the position of the adapter to let you know which toggle was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should implement your Own Adapter, Overriding `SimpleCursorAdapter.getView()` to get what you want. [Here](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Creating-Lists-Using-The-Android-Listactivity/3/) is an example I found